# Не получается создать treeview в angular из обьекта Observable<Object>

Tags: json, angular, treeview, angular8

Я в angular новичок , пытаюсь сделать Treeview типа :[image: пример TreeView]

Из объекта `Observable<Node>` с полями:

```
id?: number;
parentId?: number;
title?: string;
children?: Array<Node>;
```

JSON ответ от сервера выглядит вот так:

```
  {
   "id":null,
   "parentId":null,
   "title":"Статьи",
   "children":[
      {
         "id":6600000010000640471,
         "parentId":null,
         "title":"Первый подраздел аналитических материалов",
         "children":[
            {
               "id":6600000010000640475,
               "parentId":6600000010000640471,
               "title":"Подраздел",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "id":6600000010000640574,
                     "parentId":6600000010000640475,
                     "title":"22222222222",
                     "children":null
                  },
                  {
                     "id":6600000010000640572,
                     "parentId":6600000010000640475,
                     "title":"Для теста публикации",
                     "children":null
                  },
                  {
                     "id":6600000010000640573,
                     "parentId":6600000010000640475,
                     "title":"111111111111",
                     "children":null
                  },
                  {
                     "id":6600000010000640476,
                     "parentId":6600000010000640475,
                     "title":"Статья",
                     "children":null
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":6600000010000640474,
               "parentId":6600000010000640471,
               "title":"Аналитическая статья 1",
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Я пытаюсь использовать material ,но во всех примерах используется интерфейс и переменная , которая выглядит вот так :**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть ли способ привести обьект,который я получаю к такому виду ?
или лучше не использовать метариал в данном случае?
С Ув.